# how to use mutate c_across when there's multiple "." arguments in the same line

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, rowwise

I am trying to use `rowwise %>% mutate_at(ifelse())`, I had previously successfully got this to work with dplyr version < 1.0.0 using mutate_at, but am unsure how to accomplish it using its new `across` function.

Here is a subset of rows and columns from my data frame

```
data <- data.frame(level_1_name = c("coverage.modifier", "coverage.modifier", "something_else"),
                   level_1_type = c("static", "static", "static"),
                   level_1_a = c(NA, "1", "2"),
                   level_2_name = c("something_else", "something_else", "something_else"),
                   level_2_type = c("static", "static", "static"),
                   level_2_a = c(NA, "1", "2"),
                   stringsAsFactors = F)
```

And what I want to accomplish can be done with the following

```
library(dplyr) ; library(rlang) ; library(tidyselect) ; library(magrittr)
data %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate_at(vars(which(grepl(pattern = "coverage.modifier", .)) + 2),
              funs(ifelse(eval_tidy(sym(gsub("_a", "_name", as_name(quo(.))))) == "coverage.modifier" && is.na(.), "", .))) %>%
    ungroup()
```

with the output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 6
  level_1_name      level_1_type level_1_a level_2_name   level_2_type level_2_a
  <chr>             <chr>        <chr>     <chr>          <chr>        <chr>    
1 coverage.modifier static       ""        something_else static       NA       
2 coverage.modifier static       "1"       something_else static       1        
3 something_else    static       "2"       something_else static       2
```

how can I recreate this using `mutate` and `c_across` instead of `mutate_at`? Thank you!

Comment: what do you even try to acheive here? Is it simply about how to use ifelse with across or is it about the complete code? I do not really understand what you do there and why you do it.

Comment: @mnist this data frame would have many of these `levels` , I only included the first two. There are instances where a level's name (such as level_1_name) is "coverage.modifier" and the corresponding value (level_1_a) is NA, in this exact case I want to convert that to "". I use mutate_at so that I only perform this action on the levels that contain "coverage.modifier", and I use rowwise because ifelse(is.na()) requires rowwise evaluation. I make use of the fact that the value column for a corresponding name column is always exactly 2 columns to the right of it in the vars() argument.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood correctly, you want to take all columns with names like '*{something}*_a'  and replace `NA`s with `''`, but only on rows where the corresponding column named '*{something}*_name' has the value `'coverage.modifier'`.

Here's one way to do it with `across`:

```
data %>%
    mutate(across(ends_with('_a'),
                  ~replace(.,
                           is.na(.) &
                               grepl('coverage.modifier',
                                     cur_data()[[sub('_a$', '_name', cur_column())]]),
                           '')))
```

Comment: I was gonna say how about c_across() but it turns out you dont need rowwise() for method, so it works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: @Voy, happy to help!  FYI, you can click the checkmark to accept this answer.  Then it no longer shows as "unanswered" when people search, plus then I get those precious meaningless internet points. ;)